# How to check id which I used from a table that related with other multiple table?

Tags: laravel

When I want to delete a row from table I want to check the tables which use the id of this row. If used then it doesn't allow to delete.

Comment: How you consider id in used? You mean it available in other table? Please give some more details.

Comment: I believe that's called [referential integrity](https://www.google.com/search?q=database+id+referential+integrity). Also see [Maintaining Referential Integrity - Good or Bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5794417/608639) and [Laravel check for constraint violation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26363271/608639)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check whether specific column(containing other table's key) in the row is empty or null and if it is empty then delete the row otherwise skip it.
You have two ways in which you can do it-

1. using eloquent get the row by primary key and check the property on collection.
2. write a stored procedure in the database and call it in your Laravel code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `deleting` model event to check if the relationships exist. If they do, then prevent the delete.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events

If you create an observer for your model, you can use something like this:

```
public function deleting($model)
{
    if($model->someRelation->count()) {    // replace ->someRelation with whatever you want to check
        return false;   // prevent delete
    }
    if($model->anotherRelation->count()) {
        return false;   // prevent delete
    }
}
```